# Is there a way to partially match a Typescript string type?

Tags: typescript

I have type that looks like this:

```
export type RoutePermissions =
  | 'page:mypage1/subroute1'
  | 'page:mypage1/subroute2'
  | 'page:mypage1/subroute3'
  | 'page:mypage2/subroute1'
  | 'page:mypage3/subroute1'
```

I want to add a type that matches the type partially, for example:

```
type PartialRouteMatchType = ???;
const partialRouteMatch = (partialRoute: PartialRouteMatchType) => {};
partialRouteMatch('page:mypage1'); // ok
partialRouteMatch('page:mypage2'); // ok
partialRouteMatch('page:mypage22'); // should fail
```

Is this possible in Typescript?
Thank you!

EDIT: Apologies, the first example wasn't good. Added more detail.

Comment: What does "partially" mean here? Only `page:xxx` and no more? What if you have more subroutes?

Comment: Sorry @caTS, updated my example, let me know if it's a bit more clear.
I want to make sure that the string passed into the function always partially matches the defined type.

Comment: So, it only matches `page:mypage1`, `page:mypage2`, and `page:mypage3`? And no more?

Comment: Yes  Basically it should match the start of the string if possible

Comment: Should it match `"pag"`?  What about `"page:mypage1/sub"`?  What does "partially" mean here?  If you only mean "stuff before the slash" you should say that explicitly in the question.  Otherwise people will interpret your requirements differently and you'll get a bunch of answers you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```
type PartialRouteMatchType = RoutePermissions extends `${infer S}/${string}` ? S : never;
```

Here we have just defined a type that infers all the strings that start each string in the type `RoutePermissions`. Pretty simple and efficient and requires no changes to anything else. Also, it works even if the routes contain more subroutes i.e. `"page:mypage1/one/two/three"` still results in `"page:mypage1"`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEROVN)

Comment: This is very clever.
I also had a use case where some of the routes didn't have a slash, i.e.
`page:mypage`

And your solution still worked

`type PartialRouteMatchType = RoutePermissions extends | `${infer S}/${string}` | `${infer S}` ? S  : never;`


Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a function which only accepts sub-strings of a union of string literal types, then maybe this will help you.

```
const partialRouteMatch = <T extends string>(
    partialRoute: RoutePermissions extends infer U 
      ? U extends `${string}${T}${string}`
        ? T 
        : never
      : never
) => {};
```

```
partialRouteMatch('page:mypage1');   // ok
partialRouteMatch('page:mypage2');   // ok
partialRouteMatch('page2/subroute'); // ok
partialRouteMatch('page:mypage22');  // fails
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKECuNgAVhQC2AlgM6nEQB2pcAvALABQccAPnAORgCGA5sABchZP2ABGAPSlMAIyhYc4zs1YduY4aIFSZ8xcABMKluy68BWixOlyF2YAGYTa85pHXDt-Q%20WqzGpYeYo7e9komzMwAxtSk8LywxDwANhgOALI8MNEAFvRwADwAKnCgOFQAJrTxUMRUfAB8ABT%20rIkwyWkGgugG%20ERkFHFlIBXVcPUAZgRwAKpwbaxwAPzzo%20O0AAYAJADetfV8AL77xacHMHUNx1tLy6twpffLvVTAAG4EL2%20f30wASnojTge2OAG4okwOl10jgsjlcs1AkJgjpOADwctJJI4BAANbMGGpOHABF5ZHWKxiYyY7G4glEnhJEkGclIlFePThYAYrE4vGE6HMzqszLZCko6kCQy0rFwAWkXJYFKVOBTHjEFJAA)

---

or maybe you want the substring to only start at the beginning of the string.

```
const partialRouteMatch = <T extends string>(
    partialRoute: RoutePermissions extends infer U 
      ? U extends `${T}${string}`
        ? T 
        : never
      : never
) => {};

partialRouteMatch('page:mypage1');   // ok
partialRouteMatch('page:mypage2');   // ok
partialRouteMatch('page2/subroute'); // fails
partialRouteMatch('page:mypage22');  // fails
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKECuNgAVhQC2AlgM6nEQB2pcAvALABQccAPnAORgCGA5sABchZP2ABGAPSlMAIyhYc4zs1YduY4aIFSZ8xcABMKluy68BWixOlyF2YAGYTa85pHXDt-Q%20WqzGpYeYo7e9komzMwAxtSk8LywxDwANhgOALI8MNEAFvRwADwAKnCgOFQAJrTxUMRUfAB8ABT%20rIkwyWkGgugG%20ERkFHFlIBXVcPUAZgRwAKpwbaxwAPzzo%20O0AAYAJADexQC%20%207X1fIdbS8urcKVXy71UwABuBPePL29MAJT0jXB7Q4AbiiTA6XXSOCyOVyzUCQmCOk43yBy0kkjgEAA1sxwalIcBoXk4dYrGJjCi0RjsbieEl8QYibD4V49OFgMjUei4FMeMQUqRafTuplssT4WSBIYKai4NzefzSEA)

Answer (score 0):

You want a string [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```
type PartialRouteMatchType = `page:mypage1${string}`;
const partialRouteMatch = (partialRoute: PartialRouteMatchType) => {};

partialRouteMatch('page:mypage1'); // fine
partialRouteMatch('bad'); // error
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.9.0-dev.20220914#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKECuNgAVhQC2AlgM6nEQB2pcAvAFBxwA+cA5GAIYDmwAXIWS9gARgD0pTACMoWHKPZNWHbn0HC+EqbPnAATEuZtOIjWrGSZc7MADMShk6Qo4uLrGJcANhlsBZLhgAYwALABVkVDo4AAMLcxFRABIAb1IYKGIqHgBfWIBuBmDqDLhuTx8-HECQ0Po4AAoKmC9fPX43D1aqvVqwyJQASnoAPjhU3KKWturgftDG03UhC0UhgrhxcTgAM2zgBhnegKCwpekuABN2Da2dgjkoBiA)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your response! This doesn't match my use case, I have updated the description with better example. Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

Going by the accepted answer it looks like Grandas meant they wanted to match the *root of the route* (a string partial match to the first slash only or end-of-string), not a *partial match of the route* (a string partial match to any slash or end-of-string).

I'm going to make my answer about the latter in case anyone needs it, because unfortunately caTS' elegant inference [wont work for this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgEoHsCuxoF4oAoCwAUFMVAORgCGA5hAFwC241EADKQD6ElmU0NM0AjAHoAzqgBGAJzQZBHLiXLN+vCCPHTZEAEwKiStauYbJM9BADM+7sr6M1OsWe2mtFvZwPE7dB80tndzlSQgBKAG5CUEgoADUKABsASwATFAsobDgEDIwoCAAPDAA7VNEoAAMAEgBvZJKAMwgpKABlAF9hOtFgKQaqDsr2GvqmlqgAFSGoAH529kmoWigSiAA3FqiCAGNkEt6oc3zsHELlhJT07TCsgD4oWo7twmFhPakpCB3gQmOIHC+Yw0NiRP7aQFGfxCUhggj-SEqaHqIL-axwhFA5FOTT-eSRKBvFoyKQAQnBFkR9gEulRrjpHlh20xUJpgVxriZhFewmJyCkogpGCpfhpOJcjIxEKxNMEeillN8XPh0tZahEypZSNlDIwmtV2vVuogABYmUA); as template literal inference only extracts up to the first slash, not exhaustively searches to infer all possible splits.

You would just need to more-descriptively list your "RoutePermissions", which will allow us to utilise template literal types without infer (basically building up the union of all possible types, as opposed to trying to crack apart a simplified union into an exhaustive list which isn't possible to an unknown depth of path).

```
type Route<
    T extends string,
    U extends string|never = never
> = `${T}${ '' | `/${U}` }`;
type ValidRoute = (
    Route<'page:mypage0'> |
    Route<'page:mypage1',
        'subroute1'|'subroute2'|'subroute3'
    > |
    Route<'page:mypage2',
        Route<'subroute1',
            'subroute2'
        >
    > |
    Route<'page:mypage3',
        'subroute1'
    >
);
const route = (x :ValidRoute) => {};

//correct
route('page:mypage0');
route('page:mypage1');
route('page:mypage1/subroute3');
route('page:mypage2/subroute1');
route('page:mypage2/subroute1/subroute2');
route('page:mypage3/subroute1');

//errors
route('page:mypage2/subroute2');
route('page:mypage12');
route('page');
route('page:mypage1/');
route('page:mypage1/subroute');
route('page:mypage1/subroute4');
```